# Creating a loop to sum from 1 to 10

Tags: python, list, loops, sum

as a beginner for Python, I am trying tp create a loop to sum up from 1 to 10. I have tried to use the formula that I have learnt during our math class back then, which is "n * (n+1) / 2", but i get an indentation error. I've created a "for ... in ..." loop and tried to put the print function outside (not with a tab). I would really appreciate, if anyone would show me the mistake. Thanks in advance.

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for a in my_list:
print(a * (a+1) / 2)
```

**Error Message:**

```
print(a * (a+1) / 2)

^

IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: _and tried to put the print function outside_ - why?

Comment: `for` must have something inside of it (indented under it).

Comment: You just have to indent the print statement [per](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/statement-indentation-comments#:~:text=Python%20Indentation,-Most%20of%20the&text=starts%20with%20indentation%20and%20ends,and%20are%20preferred%20over%20tabs.)

Comment: if you want to use sum of `n` numbers formula then why are you using list? You can get the answer by just put `a=10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, code indentation is very important.

In your example, only what is indented will be run under the `for` loop.

so you should have:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for a in my_list:
    print(a * (a+1) / 2)
```

to avoid the error.

But that still will not yield the result you are expecting, as there is a conceptual error.

You don't want to have a for loop there, instead what you want is the last element.

That can be achieved with the `[-1]` index. Have a look at [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-basics-of-indexing-and-slicing-python-lists-2d12c90a94cf), it should help you to understand python indexing.

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

a = my_list[-1]

print(a * (a + 1) / 2)
```

Now, if you want to double check that against manually iterating over the list, you have to include that as well. A final code could look like:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

sum = 0

for a in my_list:
    sum = sum + a

n = my_list[-1]

print(sum)
print(n * (n + 1) / 2)
```

Or, we can also use the `+=` operator, which increments the value of the variable by the desired amount, without having to use it on the right hand side, such that `sum = sum + a` becomes `sum += a`, finally arriving at:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

sum = 0

for a in my_list:
    sum += a

n = my_list[-1]

print(sum)
print(n * (n + 1) / 2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and detailed response. I understood every single alternative but need some time to get used to :)

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
sum=0
for a in my_list:
    sum+=a
print(a * (a+1) / 2)
```

In you don't have {}(curly braces). So, you have to do it using tab.

Comment: Python does not use curly braces in place of indentation. You also don't need to use tab (and arguably, you should use spaces).